# Exception has occurred: TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

[An image depicting what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUtx.png)

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
  File "C:\Users\csn-seth\Desktop\A Program\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    wingamble=[f"you won ${(amount)*2} in blackjack !", f"you won {(amount)*2} but you made a $10 deal with a man before and ended up winning "${(((amount)*2)-10)}.]"
                                                                                                                                                 "~~~~~~~~~~~~^^~"
The arrow points to the (-) in 2)-10).
```

Tried casting amount to an **int** no avail.

code:

```
import random as rand

iteration = 0
game = True
global bal
bal = 20

while game:
    if (iteration % 2) == 0:
        meridiem = 'AM'
    else:
        meridiem = 'PM'

    print(f'type *1:(amount of cash)* to gamble money, type *2* to work a job, type *3* to find a job, type *3* to not do anything.\nyou currently have: ${str(bal)}.\nTime: 12 {meridiem}')
    action = input('Action: ')
    if action.startswith('1:'):
        amount = str(action).split('1:')
        failgamble=[f"you gave ${amount} to a stranger he ran off with your money.", f"you won ! you won a trip to prison !", f"as you are giving money to the casino, you suddenly trip and lose conciousness. as you wake up you find out that the casino took your ${amount}"]
        wingamble=[f"you won ${(amount)*2} in blackjack !", f"you won {(amount)*2} but you made a $10 deal with a man before and ended up winning ${(((amount)*2)-10)}."]
        house = rand.randint(1,6)
        if (house % 2) == 0:
            bal = (bal - amount)
            print(failgamble[rand.randint(failgamble.count)])
        else:
            bal = (bal - amount)
            print(wingamble[rand.randint[wingamble.count]])
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information or preferably a [mre]. We can only guess what your variables contain and how the code is structured.

Comment: try adding a print(amount) before this statement and see what it is.

Comment: I have edited my problem to contain the code

Comment: `amount = str(action).split('1:')` : the result of '.split()' is a list; you probably want: `amount = int(action.split('1:')[-1])`. And, as @arrmansa commented, you should make it a habit of `print`ing your variables when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain `amount` is a tuple, a list, or a string when you mean for it to be an integer.  That's why `amount * 2` makes sense (it duplicates the list) while `amount * 2 - 10` doesn't.